# Adding new synonym to synsets in wordnet

Tags: java, wordnet

I am writing an application that queries the database semantically using wordnet to reformulate any query entered from the query interface. Now I want to add new synonyms to existing synsets in wordnet application. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I too am researching the WordNet DB.  I hope the following will help answer your question:

The answer lies within the sense table!

**The Sense Table**
[image]
**Description**

The sense table is responsible for linking together words (in the words table), with definitions (in the synset table)
The entries in the sense table are referred as “word-sense pairs” - because each pairing of a wordid with a synset is one complete meaning of a word - a “sense of the word”.
There are a total of 206,354 word senses in the WordNet database.

**Fields of note:**
field: wordid
The wordid is the link to the actual word - ie: wordid 21253 , represents the word “carry” in the words table

**field: synsetid**
The synsetid is the link to the actual definition in the synsets table.  Synsetid: 202083512 represents the definition 
 "transmit or serve as the medium for transmission" in the synsets table

**field: lexid**
The lexid is a link to the lexdomains table, which is used to specify what kind of lexical domain that the word-sense pair belongs to.  In the image belong, you can see that

**Adding a Synonym**
To add a synonym for a particular synset (definition) you would need to add a row to the sense table that links the wordid of the new word you have added to the words table, and the synset id of the synset you want the new word to be a synonym of.

Comment: were you able to build one successfully, can you direct me to some detailed work on it. I also intend to add few more words which are very new , frequently used but not added to wordnet